# Efficient way to add up usage statistics using NoSQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, aggregate, nosql

I am working on a system that tracks usage in the form of start and stop events for various things. In my current implementation, I have MySQL and each row of my table contains the start and stop timestamp, plus a unique ID to information about the event.

Running an aggregate query in MySQL to take a total of the difference of the stop and start times is very easy and relatively fast, and this returns the total minutes of usage.

I am trying to see how this would translate to NoSQL and wanted some suggestions for the best way to implement this in a performant way.

Since NoSQL seems like it doesn't really support this sort of calculation out of the box, I would have to ship a whole bunch of data to my client and do the calculations which would be extremely slow. One idea is to pre-compute the differences at insert time (basically denormalizing) which would create redundant data but make the subtractions faster.

The next problem is the additions, and that could be done for the simple aggregate case by maintaining a counter of this total sum (actually in this case I might not even need the pre-computed differences). However, the problem is that in reality I need to generate this usage across different slices of my data, so pre-computing would be difficult to do. I guess it would be possible to pre-compute a bunch of common sums, say ten or so, but then it seems the insert times would be slowed significantly because this logic has to be done for each insert. And to me one of the biggest advantages of NoSQL is the very small insert time even for large datasets.

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: "NoSQL seems like it doesn't really support..." -- there is a reason it is called NOsql.

Answer (score 1):

Let's fix the MySQL insert times.

- Batch inserts -- An `INSERT` with 100 rows runs 10 times as fast as 100 1-row `INSERTs`.  Or use `LOAD DATA`.
- (Assuming InnoDB) -- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` -- potentially a significant speedup.
- Minimize the number of indexes.